# About the distance between the caption and the main body

Tags: spacing, floats, captions

I found that there is too much space between the caption of the figure and the main body. (The caption is below the figure). I don't know how to reduce the distance among them? the code I use now is as follows,

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./Fig/ransac.eps}
\end{center}
\vspace{-4mm}
\caption{An illustration of a pair of mismatched images.}
\label{2_RANSAC}
\end{figure}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please keep separate the questions? You are allowed to ask different questions, so it is better to split this one into two as they concern different topics.

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment but `\centering` instead. (The `center` environment will add extra vertical space.)

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino  You mean that I have to split the questions in to 2 separately?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt I have replace the center with centering, But it seems that there is no use on the distance between the caption and the major body.

Comment: @happygygt Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico For the second question, use `\usepackage{url}`

Comment: @happygygt: yes, it would be better! :)

Comment: I've deleted the second question since you correctly asked a new one in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140964/27635.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- Don't use the `center` environment to center a graph inside a `figure` environment. Use the instruction `\centering` instead. This will avoid inserting lots of unwanted vertical whitespace.
- Use the parameters `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` to set the distances between (a) the graph and the caption and (b) the caption and the "end" of the `figure` (or `table`) environment.

The following examples show the results of your original code, a modication that gets by without use of the `center` environment and without `\vspace` instructions, and a final modification that also shrinks the values of `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip`, by 8 points each in the examples. The `\hrule` commands are there to outline the boundaries of the `figure` environments. I trust that these tools will let you find a setup that's to your liking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

original code:
\hrule
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./Fig/ransac.eps}
\end{center}
\vspace{-4mm}
\caption{An illustration of a pair of mismatched images.}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\hrule

\bigskip
next try:
\hrule
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./Fig/ransac.eps}
\caption{An illustration of a pair of mismatched images.}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\hrule

\bigskip
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{-8pt}
\addtolength\belowcaptionskip{-8pt}
final try:
\hrule
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{./Fig/ransac.eps}
\caption{An illustration of a pair of mismatched images.}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}
\hrule
some text \emph{after} a ``figure'' environment
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried your method. add the commanding,\hrule, \bigskip
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{-8pt},\addtolength\belowcaptionskip{-8pt}, and replace begin{center} with \centering. But it turns out useless. And there even appears a line below the caption. I really confused why does this command you suggested seem useless in my environment?

Comment: You are not supposed to put in the `\hrule`s and the `\bigskip`. They are there to make the changes more visible. The suggestion is to replace the center environment with `\centering` and if that doesn't sufficiently reduce the space, tinker with different values of `\abovecaptionskip` and \belowcaptionskip`. I would also point out that LaTeX adds `\textfloatsep` between figures and the main body of text. You can also experiment with giving that length parameter different values.