# LaTeX on the reference including the wave line

Tags: biblatex, urls

There is a reference I have to use, which is just an URL but there is a wave line (tilde) located in the middle of the URL. I don't know how to express it exactly. The code I used now is as follows:

```
@misc{33_oxfordvgg,note = {\url{http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/}},}
```

In addition, I have put this code below in the front of the latex file,

But, in the result showing in the final PDF file, the wave line is just located in the top and I could not use it to find the correct URL.

```
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=false,letterpaper=true,colorlinks = brack,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
```

And it turns out to show the reference in the pdf in the way below, just the picture shows,
[image: reference]

In fact, the waveline in loacted in the middle. But the result in the reference is located in the top. So I could not go to the correct webpage after I click on the reference of the url on the pdf file.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: For clarify, I believe the issue is the tilde being far too above the baseline. You should be able to find a duplicate; I'm unfortunately on my phone.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!!!

Comment: @SeanAllred. Sorry, I don't know exactly what you mean by finding a duplicate?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87559/27635 and at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10858/27635

Comment: Thanks @karlkoeller -- do the above fix your problem?

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks, I have seen the material you recommended. But I still do know how to deal with it.

Comment: @SeanAllred I have just, re-edited my problem with more details. I still could not figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `~` in the URL string with `$\sim$` and then recompiling your document (latex, bibtex, and latex twice more)?

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke `biblatex` and `hyperref` in the following way, you get a centered tilde and a functioning link:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyperref,backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[breaklinks=false,letterpaper=true,colorlinks
= brack,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Note that the `pagebackref` option is removed from `hyperref` and instead the `backref` option of `biblatex` is used.